# Maven bundle plugin suddently generates Manifest with wrong versions

Tags: maven, version, osgi, manifest

When building a maven projet as an OSGI bundle, I get for some dependency wrongs versions range in the import-package of the MANIFEST.
This occurs for internal dependency, I said suddently because thats works find for years and the problem occurs today.

The pom of the project looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xxxxxx.yyyy</groupId>
        <artifactId>yyyy-features</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.xxxxxx.yyyy</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.xxxxxx.yyyy.command</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <dependencies>

    [...]

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxxx.yyyy.m2m</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.xxxxxx.yyyy.m2m.config</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxxx.yyyy.importexport</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.xxxxxx.yyyy.importexport.api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    [...]

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>com.xxxxxx.yyyy.command.*</Export-Package>
                        <Karaf-Commands>*</Karaf-Commands>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and the MANIFEST looks like :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1652108014425
Build-Jdk: 11.0.11
Built-By: wwhite
Bundle-Blueprint: OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml
Bundle-Description: YYYYYYYYY yyyy
Bundle-DocURL: https://www.xxxxxx.com/
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: com.xxxxxx.yyyy.command
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.xxxxxx.yyyy.command
Bundle-Vendor: YYYYYY yyyy YYYYYY
Bundle-Version: 9.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: com.xxxxxx.yyyy.command;uses:="com.xxxxxx.yyyy.commo
 n,com.xxxxxx.yyyy.connector.spi,com.xxxxxx.yyyy.model.core
 
 [...]
 
Import-Package: com.xxxxxx.yyyy.importexport.api;version="[9.0,10)",
com.xxxxxx.yyyy.importexport.api.model;version="[9.0,10)",com.xxxxxx.yyyy.m2m
 ;version="[8.1,9)",com.xxxxxx.yyyy.m2m.bean;version="[8.1,9)",com.so
 prahr.edsn.m2m.config;version="[8.1,9)",com.xxxxxx.yyyy.m2m.config.b
 ean;version="[8.1,9)",com.xxxxxx.yyyy.m2m.utils;version="[8.1,9)"
 
 [...]
 
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/com.xxxxxx.yyyy.command.m2m.resync.Resync
 ServiceImpl.xml
Specification-Title: com.xxxxxx.yyyy.command
Specification-Vendor: XXXXXXXXXX
Specification-Version: 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Tool: Bnd-4.2.0.201903051501
```

The current project version is 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT so i expect [9.0, 10) versions range for all dependency with project version but for an obscur reason I get [8.1,9) for packages com.xxxxxx.yyyy.m2m.*

I build a denpency tree (mvn dependency:tree) but get the good dependency version 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT for project com.xxxxxx.yyyy.m2m.config.

I try many others things, building with or without Netbeans, cleaning before building, cleaning all my .m2/com/xxxxxx/yyyy

I'm struggling finding the reason of that wrong range version, so thank you if you have any ideas for me !

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by locally (i.e on my computer) building the maven project thats had wrong version before the project that depended of them.

But cant undersand the logic. The said projects had been build on the remote maven repo (Nexus) in the needed version (9.0.0-SNAPSHOT). Even if not why choosing [8.1-9.0) range version ? (8.1 is the version of the last release on the remote).